# Cancel setInterval for ajax on button click

Tags: jquery

I have a series of buttons and foreach button I have a seperate .click(function() {

ie

```
$("#approved").button().click(function() {
$("#waiting_approval").button().click(function() {
$("#department_waiting_approval").button().click(function() {
$("#department").button().click(function() {
```

I have the setInterval for ajax which refreshes the data in that div.
The problem i face is once the user clicks on a different button I would like to stop the current button click ajax call and start the new one.

Hope this makes sense, thanks in advance.

```
$("#approved").button().click(function() {

setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "holidays/academic_days.php?userid='+$('#approved_list').attr('class')",
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data) {
    jQuery("#approved_list").fadeOut( 10 , function() {
        jQuery(this).html( data);
        $('#approved_list').show();  
    $('#waiting_approval_list').hide();
            $('#department_waiting_approval_list').hide();
            $('#department_logs').hide();
    }).fadeIn( 100 );

  }
 })
}, 100);

});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be helpful:

```
var thisInterval;
$("#approved").button().click(function() {

   thisInterval=setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "holidays/academic_days.php?userid='+$('#approved_list').attr('class')",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data) {
        jQuery("#approved_list").fadeOut( 10 , function() {
            jQuery(this).html( data);
            $('#approved_list').show();  
        $('#waiting_approval_list').hide();
                $('#department_waiting_approval_list').hide();
                $('#department_logs').hide();
        }).fadeIn( 100 );

      }
     })
    }, 100);

    });
```

Make cancel button like this.

```
$("#cancel").button().click(function() {clearInterval(thisInterval)}
```

Comment: Thanks not working quite as expected. Do you know how I can setInterval on a certain part of the ajax success data like (#somediv). So the button would load the whole thing but then setInterval ona certain div and it would just keep loading that div on interval until another button is clicked.

Comment: Wasn't we were doing the same thing? It would just keep loading that div on interval until another button(#cancel) is clicked.

Comment: I mean the button would load #approved_list and then do the ajax call. Within that call setinterval for #somediv that is nested in the original #approved_list. Therefor it would load #approved_list on button click and only refresh #somediv on interval

Answer (score 1):

setInterval function returns a handler for that interval object which can later be used to clear that interval using clearInterval for example:

```
    var handler = setInterval(function(){
      console.log('interval');
    },1000);

    setTimeout(function(){
      clearInterval(handler);
    },5000);
```